# p:calendar inline write date

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

Is there a way so I can add a primefaces calendar to my xhtml page (using inline mode, I want the calendar to be seen without clicking)  and write the day I chose? I mean, I click in a date (let's say november 16th) and the date gets written below the calendar...

Modes like Popup do exactly that but I have to click in the input if I want to see the calendar...

Comment: sure, use ajax and a `h:outputText`

Comment: I never used ajax with jsf. Is it something like this?

     <p:calendar value=... id=... pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" >
    <p:ajax event="change" update="outputTextID"/>
    </p:calendar>

Comment: Yep (and start using ajax, helps a lot!)

Comment: @Kukeltje update="outputTextID" is not working, I added a listener and tried printing the date I click and it prints it, but nothing is written in the outputText

Comment: Since I have no clue how your `h:outputText` looks like, I cannot comment

Comment: <h:outputText id="outputFirstDay" />

Comment: You miss the `value` attribute here